# Changing magento table's using install script

Tags: php, magento

How to change Magento's default tables using install script of custom modules?

I need to change "eav_attribute" table's "Telephone" column using install script. My intention is to set "is_required" field to set to 1 in that table..., to get past validation.

I am a little bit new to magento, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Declare a setup resource and a module version to trigger the setup workflow for a module:

```
<config>
    <Your_Module>
        <version>0.1.0</version> <!-- whatever -->
    </Your_Module>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <your_module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Your_Module</module>
                </setup>
            </your_module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

2) Create an install script *Your/Module/sql/your_module_setup/install-0.1.0.php* which (as a matter of style) uses the `customer/setup` class:

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/setup','customer_setup');
/* @var $installer Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer->startSetup();

//Proposed edit is correct: entity is customer_address not customer
//$installer->updateAttribute('customer','telephone','is_required',false);
$installer->updateAttribute('customer_address','telephone','is_required',false);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Clear the config cache, hit any page, and this should update the attribute param.